# How do I deploy an react app to azure and change the default page

Tags: reactjs, azure

I'm trying to deploy a react app to azure. I tested that my build runs, at that works fine. When I deploy my app, I get the default 'hey, node developers' page. I have then tried to add a index.js file as described on some sites, like this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#NodeHome

but now I'm getting an error...

```
*/home/LogFiles/2020_01_13_RD0003FF73402D_default_docker.log  (https://sbwebtest.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2020_01_13_RD0003FF73402D_default_docker.log)
2020-01-13T11:39:01.618020509Z 11:39:01 0|index  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:27:21)
2020-01-13T11:39:01.619118659Z 11:39:01 0|index  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30) {
2020-01-13T11:39:01.620286813Z 11:39:01 0|index  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-01-13T11:39:01.628165973Z 11:39:01 0|index  |   requireStack: [ '/home/site/wwwroot/index.js' ]
2020-01-13T11:39:01.629324326Z 11:39:01 0|index  | }
2020-01-13T11:39:01.649097230Z 2020-01-13T11:39:01: PM2 log: App [index:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2020-01-13T11:39:01.650858410Z 2020-01-13T11:39:01: PM2 log: Script /home/site/wwwroot/index.js had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"
2020-01-13T11:39:01.657846830Z 11:39:01 PM2      | App [index:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2020-01-13T11:39:01.659306496Z 11:39:01 PM2      | Script /home/site/wwwroot/index.js had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"*
```

I have deployed using the azure tool in VS code.

Anyone know what to do ?

Comment: Remember to add more related tags next time, otherwise the person who know the solution may not see the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you are based on Windows OS, this screenshot will tell you how to fix it:

[image]

### If you are based on Linux OS, there are two ways to resolve this problem.

#### First method:

The premise of this method is you have Node.js env and have installed npm tools.

***1.add a file name index.js under the site/wwwroot.***

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var options = {
index: 'index.html'                                             //Fill path here.
};
server.use('/', express.static('/home/site/wwwroot', options));
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

***2.install express:***

run this command under the wwwroot directory,

```
npm install -save express
```

***3.restart your app service and wait for minutes.***

---

#### Second method:

***1.Create a `.htaccess` file under the root directory.***

**`.htaccess` file:**

```
DirectoryIndex public_html/index.php
```

***2.Restart your web app and wait for minutes.***

---

**This is the structure of my web app:**

[image]

**Success:**

[image]

Let me know if you have more doubts.

Comment: @user267750 Hi, any update? If my solution solve your problem, please mark my answer as the answer of this question to end this question. [The link about How to mark.](https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/work/mark.png)

Comment: Been busy with other work, but will try next week. I will keep you updated. thanks !!

Comment: @BowmanZhu I have faced the similar issue and just installed node module (npm install -save express) and it works fine.